# can activeMQ read public synonyms

Tags: activemq-classic

Currently in my application activeMQ is generating 3 table at run time , but whole application is using table through public synonym which is generated at run time. So when ever i created 3 tables manually despite of generating ActiveMQ at run time .
Then ActiveMQ is not able to access table from public synonym.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Include your code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Please try below methods (based on the info which you have given) and also can you please mention the username you are setting in your activemq.xml for below tag

```
<property name="username" value="?????"/>
```

1.After creating public synonym request you to please grant to the table names . Follow below steps

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM ACTIVEMQ_MSGS
FOR <SCHEMA OR USER>.ACTIVEMQ_MSGS;

grant select on ACTIVEMQ_MSGS to public or <schema name which you have given tag of activemq.xml <property name="username" value="?????"/> >;
```

similarly for other 2 tables as well

I believe a public synonym can be queried by any user, but if you want to have access to the base table you need to have a grant on that table.

a synonym is just an alias for the table.

Please do revert back in case you didn't found your answer.